# SharePoint and the fantastic System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: sharepoint-2013, invalidoperationexception

This is not a question! We have found the solution (I post it later as answer). I hope this can be helpful to someone.
Our custom wcf service (deployed in SharePoint 2013) threw a InvalidOperationException inside a SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges block. We found many articles on the net with strange and unexplained solutions... 
So, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Someone has changed the App Pool Account for SharePoint-80 ... but not in the right way: not using the SharePoint Central administration.
At this [link](http://nikpatel.net/2012/01/25/best-practices-to-change-app-pool-account-for-sharepoint-web-applcation/) is explained the right way. After follow this simple example all works fine.
I don't know why only the code with RunWithElevatedPrivileges blocks didn't work...